# How references can bind to prvalues?

Tags: c++, reference, temporary, prvalue

[cppreference says that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime): a temporary object is created when a reference is bound to prvalue. Do they mean const lvalue references and rvalue references?:

> Temporary objects are created when a prvalue is materialized so that it can be used as a glvalue, which occurs (since C++17) in the following situations:
>
> - binding a reference to a prvalue

If they mean that, does rvalue references and const lvalue reference bound to prvalues of same type creates a temporary? I mean, does this is happening:

```
const int &x = 10; // does this creates temporary?

int &&x2 = 10; // does this creates temporary?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only references that are allowed to bind to object rvalues (including prvalues) are rvalue references and `const` non-`volatile` lvalue references. When such a binding occurs to a prvalue, a temporary object is materialized. Temporary materialization thus occurs in both of the OP's examples:

```
const int &x = 10;
int &&x2 = 10;
```

The first temporary (with value 10) will be destroyed when `x` goes out of scope. The second temporary (also with value 10, although its value can be modified using `x2`) will be destroyed when `x2` goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks alot. I just need to ask, cppreference says that, temporaries are created when prvalue is materialized and that's occur when [those situations] (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) are met. And then said that temporary materialization (i.e prvalue materialization i.e prvalue->xvalue) is occur in [those other situations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization). Now what the "reference" I should revisit?

Comment: @cpper Please post a new question.

Comment: `x` is bound **indirectly** to the resultant xvalue while `x2` is bound **directly** to the resultant xvalue. Right?

Comment: @John That needs to be posted as a separate question.